# Analysis c# Project with Jenkins and Sonarqube - Error calling MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end

Tags: c#, jenkins, msbuild, sonarqube

I am trying to analysis a c# project with SonarQube and Jenkins.

I download the MSBuild SonarQube Runner plugin and I run my analyze to C# Project from the Command Line like this.

**cd\**

**cd ci\Test\CodeCamper**

**rem ---------------  STEP 1 -----------------**

**MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin /k:ProjectCSharp:CodeCamper /n:CodeCamper /v:1.0 /d:sonar.resharper.cs.reportPath="c:\ci\test\codecamper\resharper.xml" /d:sonar.resharper.solutionFile="c:\ci\test\codecamper\CodeCamper.sln"**

**rem ---------------  STEP 2 -----------------**

**C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe "c:\ci\test\codecamper\CodeCamper.sln" /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0**

**rem ---------------  STEP 3 -----------------**

**"C:\ci\sonarqube\AddOn\JetBrains.ReSharper.CommandLineTools\inspectcode.exe" /output="c:\ci\test\codecamper\resharper.xml" "c:\ci\test\codecamper\CodeCamper.sln"**

**rem ---------------  STEP 4 -----------------**

**MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end**

Run successfully.

Now I create a job in jenkins and call the cmds in the build step, i choose execute batch windows command. I put inside all the commands like before, and lunch the build.

The step1 , step2 and step3 run successufully, but the step4, ends up with error.

Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace C:\CI\jenkins\Jenkins\jobs\CodeCamper2\workspace
[workspace] $ cmd /c call C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\hudson2830193841329867261.bat

C:\CI\jenkins\Jenkins\jobs\CodeCamper2\workspace>cd\

C:>cd ci\Test\CodeCamper

C:\CI\Test\CodeCamper>rem ---------------  STEP 4 -----------------

C:\CI\Test\CodeCamper>MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end 
Default properties file was found at C:\CI\sonarqube\AddOn\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
Loading analysis properties from C:\CI\sonarqube\AddOn\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
Post-processing started.
WARNING: File is not under the project directory and cannot currently be analysed by SonarQube. File: D:\TEMP.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.AssemblyAttributes.cs, project: c:\ci\test\codecamper\CodeCamper.Data.Contracts\CodeCamper.Data.Contracts.csproj
WARNING: File is not under the project directory and cannot currently be analysed by SonarQube. File: D:\TEMP.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.AssemblyAttributes.cs, project: c:\ci\test\codecamper\CodeCamper.Data\CodeCamper.Data.csproj
WARNING: File is not under the project directory and cannot currently be analysed by SonarQube. File: D:\TEMP.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.AssemblyAttributes.cs, project: c:\ci\test\codecamper\CodeCamper.Model\CodeCamper.Model.csproj
WARNING: File is not under the project directory and cannot currently be analysed by SonarQube. File: D:\TEMP.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.AssemblyAttributes.cs, project: c:\ci\test\codecamper\CodeCamper.Web\CodeCamper.Web.csproj
The SONAR_RUNNER_HOME environment variable is not required and will be ignored.
SONAR_RUNNER_OPTS is not configured. Setting it to the default value of -Xmx1024m
Calling the sonar-runner...
Files was unexpected at this time.
The sonar-runner did not complete successfully
21:38:18.51  Creating a summary markdown file...
Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1

**C:\CI\Test\CodeCamper>exit 1 
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE.**

What i am missing here?

My apologies for my bad english.

Best regards,

Lopes.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late reply but just seen this post, seems your issue is on the sonnarqube end step

```
MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end Default properties file was found at C:\CI\sonarqube\AddOn\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
```

This could be caused due the XML for configuration is not in the same folder (exe, dll and xml have to be at the same level, in your case at C:\CI\sonarqube\AddOn\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner). As it is not there it tried to use a default configuration file but this wont have any of the information required to publish on your sonarqube server.

Comment: Dear Kanekotic,

thank you for the reply, I will check , and I let you know if works.

Best regards.

Lopes.

Comment: please let me know if you have anything specific on your file structure or configure file, so i can help you troubleshoot

Comment: Hello Kanekotic,  sorry about the late reply, but I was sick. I try what you said,  I copy the 3 files , exe, dll,   xml to the solution folder and I´ve the same error. Best regards